# Copy http Cache-Control to a new server

Tags: php, curl, http-headers

I have a setup where we curl one of our solr servers and use the http header Cache-Control to cache the results.

We're setting up a new server that will be making the same calls, is there a way to move the cache from the old server and copy it over to the new server?  Where would that be stored by default on linux?

Comment: You have set up a cache, but don't know where the cache is actually stored?

Comment: in php, i simply set the curl http header to include Cache-Control: max-age=1 day

Comment: I don't follow.  The Cache-Control header is typically a server RESPONSE header not a REQUEST header that you would set in a cURL request. cURL isn't going to magically cache responses because you have added such a header. You would have to get the response and place it into a caching mechanism of your choice. Then you would have to build a way to check the cache for the existence of a value and make a cURL call to fetch a new response if one isn't cached.

Comment: it is possible that our custom solr engine listens for that header, and sets the response header to match.  But are you saying that if that's set, our server isn't caching the result, instead the other server is?

Comment: That may be possible that the server adjusts its response headers based on such a request header, though there is no such functionality in the base SOLR installation.  Regardless, that still isn't going to make cURL cache anything. cURL doesn't have any built-in support for content caching.

Comment: ok, thanks.  I guess I just misunderstood everything that was happening.  So using the same call on the new server should work just fine and shouldn't have to prime any cache again.  Great.

Comment: My guess is that you don't actually have a cache at all.  Try it out though.  Make several of the same requests in a row on your app server, and see if each of them gets sent to the SOLR server.

Comment: Hey Mike, can you add a comment on the ticket so that I can accept that answer that I'm not caching.  Just want you to get the points for helping :)

Comment: Done. Hope I provided some help at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on our discussion in comments above. It seems like you do not currently have an operational cache.  PHP cURL does not have any built-in caching mechanism, you you will need to implement you own caching mechanism should you need it.